# How do I access a network drive that won't upgrade past SMBv1 w/ devices that have been Updated to SMBv2 & v3?

Tags: windows, security, hard-drive, storage

I am getting Network drive error code 0x80070035 because the network drive is no longer being updated or supported by the manufacturer.

I still want to use the drive since its a good drive, but I don't want to roll back all the connections the workstations to before SMB v2 or v3

How do I only have that connection (from workstation to older network drive) be v1 while keeping everything else v2 & v3?

Could there be other possible deeper issues that might be triggering this as a false positive?

Answer (score 0):

Can you navigate to the Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off > check the box for "SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support"